# MySQL version 7.0.6-IR3 issue when try to connect to db

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

I got below error when i try to connect to MySQL db.

> Inheritance security rules violated by type:
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices'. Derived types must
>   either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less
>   accessible.

Below is the entityframework config:

```
 <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=7.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Before this i'm using MySQL 6.9.9 and no error happen.
Please help.

Comment: Same error happens to me

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in MySql connector, tracked here:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89134

Workaround is to downgrade to lower version connector  (like the one you were using)